# how to configure spring security for spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to make a web application that uses:
SpringBoot,
Mysql,
JDBC
, MVC, DAO
Thymeleaf,
IntelliJ

And I'm trying to figure out how Spring security works (which I'm having a lot of difficulty with).
My views are organized as follows:

```
resources(folder): - ________static(folder)
                         |____templates(folder):__________images(folder)
                                                      |___userOnly(folder):_____header.html
                                                      |                       |__help.html
                                                      |                       |__menu.html
                                                      |                       |__newDocForm.html
                                                      |                       |__profil.html
                                                      |
                                                      |__firstPage.html
                                                      |__header.html
                                                      |__home.html
                                                      |__index.html
                                                      |__inscriptionForm.html
                                                      |__loginPage.html
```

I would like to do that unidentified users can access all views except those contained in "userOnly" and that my "loginPage" page is used as the login page.

If I understood correctly, I must create a class that inherits from "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter".
What I have done.
And then configure "configure", which I can't do correctly :(

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/userOnly/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/loginPage.html");
    }
}
```

Sorry if my questions seems strange but english is not my first language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Spring-Boot 2.7 the use of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated. If you're using Spring-Boot 2.6 or older the other answers might suit you better.

To my best knowledge the recommended way for defining security config in Spring-Boot 2.7 is as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig
{
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/userOnly/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .loginPage("/loginPage.html");
        http.logout()
            .permitAll();
        // @formatter:on
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The use of web.ignoring() in the answer from `voucher_wolves` is, I believe, not recommended, instead one should add those cases to `http.mvcMatcher().permitAll()`.
On a side note, I would personally recommend whitelisting the public pages and adding authentication to everything else, (for example a public folder). This way if you forget to add security to a link it's not public by default.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)
It's seams to work but I was planning to use "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter" to do the authentification with JDBC and MySQL.
Do you known how I can do that without using it (because is deprecated) ?

Comment: This spring blog should have the information needed to set up base jdbc authentication for the new method. As it's weekend now i don't have code example on hand
https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: thanks again but I think that the part "JDBC Authentication" in your link it's more to use the user and password use for accessing the DB  and wath I would like to do it's be able to log using using the data inside my table "Diabetic" from my DB "TFE".
But thanks anyway fot trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Spring security what URL are public with something like this -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String[] PUBLIC_URLS = {"/public/*"};

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/userOnly/**").hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/loginPage.html");
  }
  
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    List<RequestMatcher> matchers =
    Arrays.asList(urls).stream().map(url -> new 
    AntPathRequestMatcher(url)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    web.ignoring().requestMatchers(new OrRequestMatcher(matchers));
  }
}
```

With **OrRequestMatcher** , you can create list of all URLs which you need to be public.
You can also use **NegatedRequestMatcher** to get all the private URL

```
   RequestMatcher privateUrlMatcher =  new 
   NegatedRequestMatcher(publicUrlMatcher);
```

I also suggest you to keep all public url under /src/main/resources/static/publicui and all private under /src/main/resources/static/privateui and have public permission for /publicui/*

Answer (score 0):

try the following in your SecSecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        
            .antMatchers("/users").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/lib/allBooks")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/lib").permitAll();
        
        http       
        .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Just modify the parameters set for your application. if you don't have login form yo can skip

```
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/lib/allBooks")
                .permitAll()
```