# Spring boot security - how to use SecurityFilterChain for authentification?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to make a web application that uses: SpringBoot, Mysql, JDBC , MVC, DAO Thymeleaf, and IntelliJ.

And I'm trying to figure out how Spring security works (which I'm having a lot of difficulty with).
I have previously asked for help in this post:
[how to configure spring security for spring boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72487751/how-to-configure-spring-security-for-spring-boot-project)
And someone explain to me that I shouldn't use the class `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` because is deprecated but use instead `SecurityFilterChain`.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig
{
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/userOnly/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .loginPage("/loginPage.html");
        http.logout()
            .permitAll();
        // @formatter:on
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

It's working perfectly and I thank again Ralan for is help
But doing so I can't figure out how to use JDBC and the table that contains my users in my database MySQL for the authentification.

Sorry if my question seems strange but English is not my first language

Comment: If you have a hard time i suggest you go through the reference documentation

Comment: If you would like to learn about the Spring Security architecture and the `SecurityFilterChain` there is a detailed [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html) in the reference docs. There is also a [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/jdbc.html) on JDBC authentication.